# Como diferenciar entre un servicio y otro en la injección de dependencias con .NET Core cuando se usa una interfaz

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tengo esta aplicación de consola y tengo 2 clases que implementan la misma interfaz(IGetDirectories) pero cuando agrego los servicios en la injección de dependencias me ejecuta el  método de el último servicio registrado, como se hace para diferenciarlos o más bien para indicarle en el host.Services.GetRequiredService() el de cual clase debe ejecutar???

```
    class Program
    {
        
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host=await HostConfig(args);

            string route = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "ARCHIVOS");

            await host.Services.GetRequiredService<IGetDirectories>().readXML(route);
        }

        static Task<IHost> HostConfig(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            BuildConfig(builder);
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                    services.AddTransient<IGetDirectories, GetDirectories>();
                    services.AddTransient<IGetDirectories, Validations>();
                }).Build();

            return Task.FromResult(host);
        }
        
        static Task BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder configuration)
        {
            configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings." +
                $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al parecer esto no debe hacerse usando la interfaz, sino que hay que registrar las clases directamente en el contenedor de esta forma:

```
 class Program
    {
        
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host=await HostConfig(args);

            string route = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "ARCHIVOS");

            await host.Services.GetRequiredService<GetDirectories>().readXML(route);
        }

        static Task<IHost> HostConfig(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            BuildConfig(builder);
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                    services.AddTransient<GetDirectories>();
                    services.AddTransient<Validations>();
                }).Build();

            return Task.FromResult(host);
        }
        
        static Task BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder configuration)
        {
            configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings." +
                $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```